# HOWTO create full list of Contacts in ON HOLD status

Tags: contacts, email, opt-out

I may be missing something, but I'm trying to exclude (from a contact export list) all contacts that have a "ON HOLD" status for their primary email, particularly if it's an Opt-Out, but Bounce would be useful as well. Using Advanced Find, I could find those contacts who set an Opt-Out on their own by checking Opt-Out in one of our mailings. Also, I can find some of these under Contacts > Contact Reports > Constituent Detail by filtering that report on "Do not bulk email" or "Do not email". However, it does not seem to pick up folks who have requested me personally to opt them out, which I've done manually. Any help for the COMPLETE list of contacts with "On Hold Opt Out" status, whether set by email response or by a CiviCRM admin, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the answer lies in the **Export**, *not* the filter to create the list. I just added 3 Individual contact columns to the Export: (i) "No Bulk Emails (User Opt Out)", (ii) "Do Not Email", (ii) "On Hold: Primary". It evidently worked. The "Primary-On Hold" column set to 1 with the other two blank grabs the Bounces. The first 2 columns provide Opt-Out and Privacy settings, no matter whether set via email response or manually by admin. Even though the answer was simple, I hope this helps someone else looking to do the same.